# Is it possible to write IIgs floppies from a Powermac 7100?

Tags: apple, apple-iigs

I haven't gotten around to making/sourcing a cable for ADTPro, but I was thinking perhaps I can just write a few disks with a 7100 I have sitting around since those drives can read/write GS and PC disks.

I have several `.2mg` disk images that I want to write, but I can't seem to find any solution that works.  Perhaps I need to try a different format?

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to use a IIgs side utility to unpack disk archives onto real disks.

- First stop would be Sheppy's [DiskMaker](http://www.sheppyware.net/apple-ii-software/diskmaker.html), a USD 5.- shareware utility, the gold standard here and youterpart to the original [ImageMaker](http://www.sheppyware.net/apple-ii-software/imagemaker.html).
- Further there is Ninjaforce's [ASIMOV](http://www.ninjaforce.com/html/products_asimov_docs.html) utility, free of charge.

Either should work as .2MG files are (*1) what's in the IIgs world called a '[Universal Disk File](http://wiki.apple2.org/index.php?title=Emulators_Part_3#2IMG_Universal_Format)'.

Now, if you're in a real DIY mode, then there is [CiderPress](https://a2ciderpress.com/index.htm), a great (Windows) utility to handle compressed (.SHK) files. After all, the universal format is based on [ShrinkIt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ShrinkIt).

---

*1 - Usually, as file extensions are volatile.